# What does the underscore(_) mean in elisp?

Tags: lambda, emacs, elisp, naming-conventions

I'm reviewing neotree package code out of emacs packages.
I don't know the meaning of the underscore(_) in the macro definition below.

**(lambda (&rest _))**

Full definition of the macro as follows.

```
(defmacro neotree-make-executor (&rest fn-form)
  "Make an open event handler, FN-FORM is event handler form."
  (let* ((get-args-fn
          (lambda (sym) (or (plist-get fn-form sym) (lambda (&rest _)))))
         (file-fn (funcall get-args-fn :file-fn))
         (dir-fn (funcall get-args-fn :dir-fn)))
    `(lambda (&optional arg)
       (interactive "P")
       (neo-global--select-window)
       (neo-buffer--execute arg ,file-fn ,dir-fn))))
```

Answer (score 18):

The underscore is a valid symbol name. The convention for the byte compiler is that an unused argument name should start with an underscore in order to avoid the "Unused lexical variable" warning during compilation.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to [elisp reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html)

11.9.4 Using Lexical Binding
...

```
lexical-binding [Variable]
    If this buffer-local variable is non-nil, Emacs Lisp files and buffers are evaluated
    using lexical binding instead of dynamic binding. (However, special variables are still
    dynamically bound; see below.) If nil, dynamic binding is used for all local variables.
    This variable is typically set for a whole Emacs Lisp file, as a file local variable (see
    Section 11.11 [File Local Variables], page 163). Note that unlike other such variables,
    this one must be set in the first line of a file.
```

...

```
(To silence byte-compiler warnings about unused variables, just use a variable name that
start with an underscore. The byte-compiler interprets this as an indication that this is a
variable known not to be used.)
```

Comment: In the latest (not released at the moment of writing) `Emacs 28.0.50` get to the relevant `Info` section with `C-h i m Elisp <RET> g <Converting to Lexical Binding>`.